# How do I loop through collections in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to loop through all the collections in the underlying connection in Mongoose:

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    db = mongoose.connection;

describe('Blog Tests', function () {

    before(function () {
        console.log('before called');
        db.on('error', console.error);

        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb', function(err){
            if(err)console.err(err);

            // never loops through collections at this point!
            for (var i in mongoose.connection.collections) {
                console.log(mongoose.connection.collections[i]);
                // will drop collection here
            }
        });
    });

    after(function(){
        console.log('after called');
        if(db.db._state === 'connected'){
            console.log('closing db');
            db.close();
        }
    });

    it('Can add a blog post', function (done) {
        db.on('open', function(){
            var blogPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
                    id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                    title: {type: String, required: true},
                    content: {type: String},
                    tags: []
                }),
                BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost', blogPostSchema),
                blogPost = new BlogPost({
                    title: 'Hello World',
                    content: 'Lorem baby',
                    tags: [{"tag": "tests"},{"tag": "mocha"}, {"tag": "chai"}]
                });

            blogPost.save(function(err, saved){
                if (err) console.error(err);
                expect(saved.title).is.equal('Hello World');
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Yet it never returns the collection - and they defs exist, it just returns an empty object; not an empty array.

Can anyone spot the silly mistake?

UPDATED as per Gergo suggestion, but still not showing the collections:

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    db = mongoose.connection;

describe('Blog Tests', function () {

    before(function (done) {
        console.log('before called');
        db.on('error', console.error);

        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb', function(err){
            if(err) return console.err(err);

            // never loops through collections at this point!
            for (var i in mongoose.connection.collections) {
                console.log(mongoose.connection.collections[i]);
                // will drop collection here
            }
            done();
        });
    });

    after(function(done){
        console.log('after called');
        if(db.db._state === 'connected'){
            console.log('closing db');
            db.close();
            done();
        }
    });

    it('Can add a blog post', function (done) {
            var blogPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
                    id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                    title: {type: String, required: true},
                    content: {type: String},
                    tags: []
                }),
                BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost', blogPostSchema),
                blogPost = new BlogPost({
                    title: 'Hello World',
                    content: 'Lorem baby',
                    tags: [{"tag": "tests"},{"tag": "mocha"}, {"tag": "chai"}]
                });

            blogPost.save(function(err, saved){
                if (err) console.error(err);
                expect(saved.title).is.equal('Hello World');
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mongoose.connect` is asynchronous, the execution of the before block finishes before the callback of `mongoose.connect` is called. Use the `done` parameter and call it inside the callback:

```
before(function(done) {
    console.log('before called');
    db.on('error', console.error);

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb', function(err){
        if(err) return console.err(err);

        // never loops through collections at this point!
        for (var i in mongoose.connection.collections) {
            console.log(mongoose.connection.collections[i]);
            // will drop collection here
        }
        done();
    });
});
```

Also, change `if(err) console.err(err);` to `if(err) return console.err(err);`, because your current code continues the execution even if there was an error. It would be even better to use `if(err) return done(err);`.

**Edit:** I tested the code and it doesn't work indeed. However found that the issue is not with the asynchronous execution, but with `mongoose.connection.collections`. When connection opens, the value of `mongoose.connection.collections` is an empty object `{}`. This is the reason your for loop doesn't work as expected. However the following works:

```
mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function(err, names) {
  console.log(names);
});
```

So you could rewrite your code like this:

```
before(function(done) {
    console.log('before called');
    db.on('error', console.error);

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb', function(err) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function(err, names) {
            console.log(names);
        });

        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Gergo, unfortunately the mongoose.connection.collections inside the callback function of mongoose.connection still doesn't get the collections and the connection is open. i did modify the original code above. –  Chev 38 mins ag

Comment: Seems mongoose.connection.collections is like a cache for mongoose collections